# How do you configure runit logging

Tags: logging, runit

I am having trouble setting a service with logging using runit. Here is a brief overview of files and scripts I created according to runit's documentation and other resources I found on the internet:

I am using runit under debian, hence:

`/etc/service/test` is a symbolic link to `/etc/sv/test`.

Under `/etc/sv/test`:

```
$ ls /etc/sv/test
finish  log  run
```

And `/etc/sv/test/log`:

```
$ ls /etc/sv/test/log
config  run
```

The `run` script:

```
$ cat /etc/sv/test/run
#!/bin/sh

touch /tmp/pid
echo $$ > /tmp/pid

while true; do
    date
    sleep 3
done
```

The `finish` script:

```
$ cat /etc/sv/test/finish
#!/bin/sh

kill `cat /tmp/pid`
```

And the `log` script:

```
cat  /etc/sv/test/log/run
#!/bin/sh
exec svlogd -t /var/log/test
```

The directory `/var/log/test` exists, and the service runs.

```
$ sv s test
run: test: (pid 11547) 536s; down: log: 1s, normally up, want up
```

But the log directory is empty ... What am I missing? Where is all the logging information ?

#### update:

I also made sure all scripts are executable.

#### update 2:

It seems that the `sv` fails to start the logging script for some reason!

```
$ sv s test
run: test: (pid 14612) 5s; down: log: 0s, normally up, want up
```

#### update 3:

If you want to stop the logging script you have to issue:

```
$ sv d test/log
```

Comment: The logger is most often just a couple lines that invokes `/usr/bin/logger` with a service-specific tag or directly to some log aggregator's collection agent (to skip the parsing of syslog steps).  (Logs are really streams of events but so are often awkwardly serialized from stderr/stdout to files.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of things to address in your question that aren't related to the question (*cough* pid files *cough*) but let's tackle the question proper.

---

*First*, logging is optional.  There is no hard requirement that you have a logger for your service definition, although in most cases you will want one.

*Second*, because the logger is defacto slaved to your service, it makes sense that `./log` holds the needed settings for the logging.

*Third*, when you bring the service down, the logger is left running for a reason - it is there to capture the remaining data until the service terminates.  This was done to prevent loss of logging data, not only as the service comes down, but also if the service should crash.  *It is normal for the logger to still run even when the service is down.*  Starting the service will simply reconnect the new service instance to the existing logger.

*Fourth*, you are correct, you can stop the logger by explicitly naming it with the `sv` command.  This is in keeping with the existing `daemontools` paradigm.

*Fifth*, unless you have unusual needs for registering the failure of the svlogd program (highly unlikely) you don't need to worry about killing it, etc.  Simply signalling it to go down will cause the `runsv` supervision process to terminate it, no PIDs or `kill` commands required.

If you have further questions, I recommend contacting the [supervision mailing list](http://skarnet.org/lists.html), which is low-noise and has lots of knowledgeable people to answer your questions.  A read-only mirror can also be found on [mail-archive.org](http://www.mail-archive.com/supervision@list.skarnet.org/).

Answer (score 5):

So, after a some trial and error I found a solution.

The following things are important to notice:

1. *Configuration file*: note that it's quite counter intuitive. If you have monitored service under `/etc/sv/test`, and a logging directory under `/etc/sv/test/log` you would expect that `config` would be in `/etc/sv/test/log/config`! But notice, the file is read from where you run `svlogd`. This means:
   If your log script runs in `/var/log/test` (the last argument to `svlogd`) this is where the config 
   file is expected. So write your configuration in `var/log/test/config`List item
2. *Reloading configuration*: If you change the configuration file, you can stop and start the script with:

> ```
> $ sv down test/log
> $ sv start test/log
> ok: run: test/log: (pid 21190) 0s
> ```

Comment: You do not have to restart service/log, HUP signal is enough:

On startup, and after receiving a HUP signal, svlogd checks for each log directory log if the configuration file log/config exists, and if so, reads the file line by line and adjusts configuration for log as follows: © http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that you didn't ask about in your question, and they probably won't affect the behavior of your setup. But they are just not right and worth pointing out.

1. The `finish` script is not intended to kill the service. It is used to clean up after the service when it's finished. I don't think you need it in your use case. `runsv` already knows how to terminate the service. For that, I'll let you read more in the [`runsv` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/runit/runsv.8.en.html).
2. If you ever need the PID of the service, you can get it from `/etc/sv/test/supervise/pid`. But chances are, you will never need it.

Now to diagnosis of the problem you asked about. The logs aren't working probably because you added `log/run` after enabling the service. Therefore, the `log/supervise` directory didn't get created.

To check if what I'm  saying is true. Check if the directory is there by issuing the command `ls /etc/sv/test/log/supervise`. You should get something like this.

```
$ sudo ls /etc/sv/test/log/supervise
control  lock  ok  pid  stat  status
```

If instead you get the error `ls: cannot access '/etc/sv/test/log/supervise': No such file or directory`. Then disable and re-enable the service. ie. Remove the symlink to `runsvdir/default/` and create it again.